# How to show that this sequence is exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, exact-sequence

Let $A$ be a local ring, $\mathfrak{m}$ its maximal ideal, $\mathfrak{a}$ a proper ideal. Set $\mathfrak{n}:=\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{a}$ and $k:=A/\mathfrak{m}$. Then this sequence of $k$-vector spaces is exact
$$0\rightarrow (\mathfrak{m}^2+\mathfrak{a})/\mathfrak{m}^2 \rightarrow \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2\rightarrow \mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2\rightarrow 0$$

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It's always nice when analysing sequences for exactness (or diagram chasing in general) to be aware of what exactly the maps involved are. The first map is just an inclusion, so that's clear enough. The second map isn't that clear. What is it, exactly? At least to me, it's not even immediately obvious what the elements of $\mathfrak n/\mathfrak n^2$ look like.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, that what I am struggling at. I think first I need to transform $\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2$ into "$X/\mathfrak{m}^2$",but I am not sure what that will become...

Comment: @Arthur But I guess if the first map is an inclusion then the second map should be something like a projection to make the sequence exact.

Comment: To make the sequence exact at the rightmost term it has to be a surjective map. Surjective maps are "always" projections ("mod out by the kernel"-type stuff) the same way injections are "always" inclusions. So yeah. But you won't make much progress until you can actually figure out what they are.

Comment: I think it should be $t+m^2\to (t+a)+(m/a)^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\mathfrak{n}=\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{a}$, we have $\mathfrak{n}^2=(\mathfrak{m}^2+\mathfrak{a})/\mathfrak{a}$. Thus $\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2\cong\mathfrak{m}/(\mathfrak{m}^2+\mathfrak{a})$. On the other hand, $\frac{\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2}{(\mathfrak{m}^2+\mathfrak{a})/\mathfrak{m}^2}\cong\mathfrak{m}/(\mathfrak{m}^2+\mathfrak{a})$. Thus, $\frac{\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2}{(\mathfrak{m}^2+\mathfrak{a})/\mathfrak{m}^2}\cong \mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2$. Hence we have an exact sequence of $A$-modules
$$0\rightarrow (\mathfrak{m}^2+\mathfrak{a})/\mathfrak{m}^2 \rightarrow \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2\rightarrow \mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2\rightarrow 0.$$

Now since $\mathfrak{m}((\mathfrak{m}^2+\mathfrak{a})/\mathfrak{m}^2)=\mathfrak{m}(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)=\mathfrak{m}(\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2)=0$, we have $(\mathfrak{m}^2+\mathfrak{a})/\mathfrak{m}^2$,$\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ and $\mathfrak{n}/\mathfrak{n}^2$ are $k=A/\mathfrak{m}$-modules and the above sequence is an exact sequence of $A/\mathfrak{m}$-modules.

Comment: Why is $/mathfrak{n}^2=(/mathfrak{m}^2+/mathfrak{a})//mathfrak{a}$?

Comment: By the definition of of $J/I$ in the ring $R/I$ we must have $I\subseteq J$. If  $J/I$ is an ideal in the ring $R/I$ then we may have $I\not\subseteq J^2$. Thus $J^2/I$ is meaningless. So define $(I/J)^n=I^n+J/J$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the short exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow  \mathfrak a\longrightarrow  \mathfrak m\longrightarrow  \mathfrak n \longrightarrow  0$$
and tensor it with $k$, to obtain the exact sequence
$$\mathfrak a\otimes_Ak\longrightarrow  \mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2\longrightarrow  \mathfrak n\otimes_Ak \longrightarrow  0.$$

Now, $\quad\mathfrak n\otimes_Ak=\mathfrak n/\mathfrak m\mathfrak n=(\mathfrak m/\mathfrak a)\big/(\mathfrak m\cdot\mathfrak m/\mathfrak a)=(\mathfrak m/\mathfrak a)\big/(\mathfrak m/\mathfrak a\cdot\mathfrak m/\mathfrak a)=\mathfrak n/\mathfrak n^2$.

On the other hand, the image of the left morphism is as well the image of $\mathfrak a$ in $=\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$  by the canonical morphisms, as the following commutative diagram shows:
\begin{matrix}
\mathfrak a\mkern-1em &\xrightarrow{\hspace{2em}}&\mkern-1em\mathfrak m\\
\downarrow\mkern-1em & & \mkern-1em\downarrow \\
\mathfrak a/\mathfrak m\mathfrak a\mkern-1em &\longrightarrow &\mkern-1em\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2
\end{matrix}
This image is $\;(\mathfrak a+\mathfrak m^2)/\mathfrak m^2$, whence the short exact sequence in your post.